# Read MySQL result from shell script

Tags: mysql, wordpress, shell, vagrant

at first, I am a very new on shell scripting, so please don't shoot me !! :)

What I try to do. I have a multi-site WordPress installation, and I like to write a script that will be able to export specific tables from the schema either by passing the site id as argument in shell script, or by set an option to export all `selected` the tables of the schema.

The WordPress, in order to recognize which table set is for which site, changes the prefix of each table set. So In example does the following :

```
wp_options
wp_1_options
...
wp_x_options
```

In addition, the WordPress store the blog id in a special table called `wp_blogs`

So, from my shell script I run the following code :

```
mysql -uUSER -pPASS -e 'SELECT `blog_id` AS `ID`, `path` AS `Slug` FROM `wp`.`wp_blogs`'
```

and I am getting the following results

```
+----+---------------------------+
| ID | Slug                      |
+----+---------------------------+
|  1 | /                         |
|  2 | /site-2-slug/             |
|  4 | /site-4-slug/             |
|  5 | /site-5-slug/             |
|  6 | /site-6-slug/             |
|  7 | /site-7-slug/             |
|  8 | /site-8-slug/             |
|  9 | /site-9-slug/             |
| 10 | /site-10-slug/            |
+----+---------------------------+
```

So, now the actual question is, how can I parse the MySql result line by line, in order to get the `ID` and the `Slug` information ?

***Side note 1*** : The whole script has been generated and run's somehow manually. I need now this information in order to automate even farther the exporting script.

***Side note 2** : The MySql executed via the `Vagrant` ssh like the following line : *

```
sudo vagrant ssh --command "mysql -uroot -proot -e 'SELECT blog_id FROM wp.wp_blogs'"
```

Comment: What do you need the ID and the slug for?

Comment: The ID will be used in order to export the required tables for each selected site, and the slug will be used to name the exported sql files. In example, if I like to export the required tables from site with ID `2`, in my command line I will enter `export.sh 2` and the script will export only the tables I need for this site. At the end, the `mysqldump` will generate an SQL file will be named `site-2-slug.sql`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save the result in a file using INTO like below:

```
SELECT blog_id, path FROM wp.wp_blogs
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/blogs.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

And then you could process it line by line either usingsed/awk/simple while loop. Say you want to search for site and replace it with mysite, you could do something like:

```
awk -F',' '{print "Id: " $1 ", path: "$2}' /tmp/blogs.csv  ##or simply cat the file.
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it in a few minutes. !!

Comment: The `awk` didn't worked for me. Actually I cannot totally understand how it works. I used the first part of your script, and this approach too : while IFS=',' read -r ID Slug; do
    echo "ID\t: $ID\nSlug\t: $Slug\n"
done < "$local_export_folder/blogs.csv"
IFS=$' \t\n'. Again thanks !!!

Comment: Apologies i missed by open quotes which i corrected now.

Comment: I used them too, but again, didn't worked to me. Propably I do something wrong with my code :)